# Watermark Emeding through LSB (Bit wise )in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

Making an android application in which trying watermark embedding(through LSB (Bit wise) )to an image only for red pixels.

I cannot embed my information behind the image

**Note: just trying to embed data on red pixels of any image**

```
 public void RGB(int height,int width,int asciiValue){
        //System.err.println("its coming");
        int redArray[]=new int[height*width];

         for(int ii=0; ii<height; ii++){

            for(int jj=0; jj<width; jj++){
                 //System.out.println("shahbaz "+  temp);
                 //System.out.println("After "+  asciiValue);

                 c = new Color(image.getRGB(ii, jj));
                System.out.println("S.No: " + count + " Red: " + c.getRed() +"  Green: " + c.getGreen() + " Blue: " + c.getBlue());
                redArray[ii+jj]=c.getRed();

                System.err.println("red "+redArray[ii+jj]);
               }

            }
    }
    int getleastbit(char asciiValue)
    {
                 int temp;
                 temp=asciiValue >> 30;
                 temp=temp<<30;
                 System.out.println("temp value"+temp);
                 return temp;

    }
    int andOperation(int redvalues)
    {
        int result=redvalues &1;
        System.err.println("and between "+redvalues+" and "+"1");
         System.out.println("red result "+result);
        return result;
    }

    int RedEmbeddingValues(int temp,int red){



                 if (red==0)

                 {
                       red =red | temp;
                       return red;
                 }
                 else if(red == 1)
                    {
                        if(temp==1)
                        red=red;
                        else
                        red=red-1;

                    }                 
                    return red;


    }

    int[] getRedArray(int height,int width,Color c)

    {
        int[] redArray=new int[height*width];
     for(int i=0;i<=width;i++)
         for(int j=0;j<=height;j++)
         {
             redArray[i+j]=c.getRed();
         }     
     return redArray;
    }



    public Pixcell(){
    readFileaddress ="C:\\Users\\Haider Ali\\Desktop\\Pro.jpg";
    writeFileaddress ="C:\\Users\\Haider Ali\\Desktop\\qaaaa.jpg";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pixcell objpixcel1 = new Pixcell();
        objpixcel1.Readfile();

       int redArray[]=objpixcel1.getRedArray(10, 15, Color.red);
     for(int i=0;i<redArray.length;i++){
      }
        ascii getascii=new ascii();
        String name=getascii.getString();
        int asciiValue=0;
        try{for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++){
            int bit=objpixcel1.getleastbit(name.charAt(i));
            int redresult=objpixcel1.andOperation(redArray[i]);
           }}
        catch(Exception e){}
        for(int i=0;i<redArray.length;i++){
        System.out.println("red "+redArray[i]);
        }
         objpixcel1.RGB(10,15,32);
         objpixcel1.Writefile();

    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the question? You should follow [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Dev-iL this is the question buddy  " I cannot embed my information behind the image "

Comment: Why can't you? Does it just not work? Do you get an exception? Does it appear in front of the image?

Comment: Look, I'm trying to help you get a solution for your problem. You should help others help you. You can find a good set of pointers on how to ask "code troubleshooting" kinds of questions [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/3372061).

Comment: the output of this code is showing but in red pixel its not adding the ascii values

Comment: Okay, let's just temporarily ignore things like "ASCII" and "Pixels" for a bit. Are you able to successfully change a byte like 254 (`1111 1110`) into 255 (`1111 1111`) or 65 (`0100 0001`) into 64 (`0100 0000`)? Also, can we assume that `Readfile` and `Writefile` are "JPEG-aware" and are losslessly decompressing and re-compressing binary data into arrays of bytes?

Comment: The indexing on your redArray seems doubtful. You have `redArray[ii+jj]=c.getRed()` seems like `redArray[ii * width + jj]=c.getRed();` would be more reasonable unless you intend to overwrite your data

Comment: @DaveDurbin thanks man let me try this out :) i'll let you know

Comment: @MirzaJhanzaib did it work? If so, please provide answer and credit.

Comment: @DaveDurbin still facing the same issue by implimenting ur suggestion "The indexing on your redArray seems doubtful. You have redArray[ii+jj]=c.getRed() seems like redArray[ii * width + jj]=c.getRed(); would be more reasonable unless you intend to overwrite your data"   but somehow i managed to fix ! it